# How are web applications vulnerable to Buffer Overflow security issue?

Tags: security, owasp

The buffer overflow issue in Java primarily have chance to happen because of issues in the JVM.

Apart from that does the developers code have chances of being vulnerable to BUFFER OVERFLOW ? Esp in custom built java/nee based web applications ?

Comment: I am looking for a simple example/scenario explaining Buffer Overflow happening in JEE Web Application and how this specific scenario is prevented. There could be N number of ways this could happen, I am just looking for any one example to help me to understand.

Note: I am having problem in visualizing a buffer overflow error in jee based web application, that is the reason I am looking for a specific example. I hope this now makes the question specific and narrows down the answer.

Comment: I added the sample to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If* you (or the libraries you use) do not use JNI (native) code in your Java application and if all JVM functions are bug free (there have been bugs in the past like media parsing) then you don't need to fear traditional buffer overflows. This is basically true for all "managed code" runtimes and one of the greatest advantages.

However you can still overflow data structures. This will not lead to severe heap or stack corruptions but it might produce deny of service, information disclosure or logical problems.

The example is simple:

```
void test() {
    char[] c = new char[10];
    c[11] = '1'; // or 10
}
```

if you try this method, it will throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception and not write to the memory location. In fact this is one of the major motivators for exceptions, if you read the [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6).

<sup>*</sup> *this is a BIG if ....*

Comment: thanks.. i saw examples of how it is prevented in regular programming languages like C/C++ but, couldn't find any example on how it can happen or prevented in Web Applications.. especially JEE based. i was looking for specific pointers on how it occurs or can be prevented in web applications..

Comment: [Managed Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) runtimes do not allow users to mess with raw pointers, and all pointer dereference/creation is guarded by the runtime to point to valid memory. Therefore you cannot access wrong memeory locations. If you ask "how" then you essentially ask how the JVM is working. That is a bit long to answer.

Comment: anyways on such array assignments, IndexOutofBound exception is going to be thrown. So what do we exactly check or write in a web application to check for this specific vulnerability ?

Comment: @yathirigan I don't understand the question, sorry. As I said, Java Web applications are NOT vulnerable to heap or stack overflows (because there are no raw pointers). If you copy something into an array without checking then the JVM will check for you. However you should be prepared to handle the exception and not do something stupid when it occurs.